# Use a Jasper variable for Arrays.asList() argument

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to split the content of a parameter and then use the .contains() method like so

```
Arrays.asList($P{names}.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*")).contains($F{name})
```

And I want to put the content in asList() in a differenet variable so that it looks like this

```
Arrays.asList($V{namesArray}).contains($F{name})
```

But I get an arror

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be
> cast to java.lang.String

What should the type of my variable be? I tried with String, Collection, ArrayList but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put the following thing in the new variable and made its type List

```
Arrays.asList($P{names}.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*"))
```

Now I can just use it like this

```
$V{namesArray}.contains($F{name})
```